# How do I set up a wireless connection after install Ubuntu Server 15.10? (systemd)

Tags: wireless, server

I tried lshw -C network and my wireless interface says DISABLED.

How do I re-enable it and connect it to the available wireless network?

It's an Intel 3945ABG and it worked fine in the installer to download the updates etc.

Comment: NOTE TO MOD: please close this question and not my other one as the other one is more relevant to the problem

Answer (score 2):

DISABLED often means that the wireless switch or button is set to turn the wireless radio off. You can check this from the terminal:

```
rfkill list all
```

`Hard blocked:yes` indicates that the wireless is blocked by the hardware switch or button. Find it and change it.

To set up the wireless in a server, I suggest you set up `/etc/network/interfaces` something like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid <your_router>
wpa-psk <your_wpa_key>
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Be sure to select a static address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router, switch or other access point. Of course, substitute your details here. Confirm that your wireless interface is `wlp3s0` with the terminal command:

```
iwconfig
```

Get the system to read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown wlp3s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp3s0
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 192.168.1.1
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Thanks. My wireless card was indeed switched off at install time, but I switched it on during the process so it's odd that it still shows as disabled. Just want to check, is setting up the interfaces file in /etc/network the 'canon' (i.e. systemd) way of setting up a wireless network for Ubuntu Server? I'm reinstalling at the moment to see if the process works better now that my wireless card is properly switched on but it seems weird having to configure the card that way and not by using some utility.

Comment: In a server, typically running headless, there is no possibility of a GUI utility and so, at least in Ubuntu and most Debian-based distros, `/etc/network/interfaces` is, as far as I know, the *only* method.

Comment: I realize that, what I meant was that systemd seems to have its own way of handling wireless connections, but it's not really well-documented, at least not for Ubuntu.

Comment: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=420280 Like this? I'm not sure either method is 'canon.'

Comment: Well that would be a start. The problem is that this issue doesn't even seem to be covered by the Ubuntu wiki. Should I put another question together asking what exactly the correct method is here?

Comment: Sure, I would be interested in the answer myself, especially documentation supporting the "correctness" of one over the other.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/695525/whats-the-correct-way-to-configure-wireless-connections-in-ubuntu-server-with-s