# What's the correct way to configure wireless connections in Ubuntu Server 15.10 with systemd?

Tags: wireless, server, intel-wireless

With reference to this question ([How do I set up a wireless connection after install Ubuntu Server 15.10? (systemd)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695464/how-do-i-set-up-a-wireless-connection-after-install-ubuntu-server-15-10-system)), is there a canon way of configuring a wireless connection using systemd, because there doesn't seem to be any up-to-date documentation on the Ubuntu wiki or elsewhere.

I have an Intel wireless 3945ABG and I'm trying to configure it but there is no clear advice on the correct way to do this with systemd. So should I use systemd or the 'old way'?

Comment: I believe @warsong means `/etc/network/interfaces` as the 'old way.'

Comment: yes :) (that method does work but it seems as if it won't *always* work going forwards)